# what does the sprout next to item stats mean?

Tags: minute-dungeon

After beating the tutorial and trying the first level a few times, I've gathered 3 weapons and 3 armor. One item of each type have a green sprout by the stats, specifically by the LIGHT stat.  What does this mean?

[image: sprout stats]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of searching, I found some information on it.  Turns out, there are elemental types in the game that have advantage/disadvantage to another element. Basically, fire beats plant beats earth beats electric beats water beats fire.  Also, dark and light are strong against each other.

This modifier appears to be a 20%change in damage. So 100 damage from a water would become 100-20 to an electric source or 100+20 to a fire source

[image: diagram]

Also, certain elements are better based on what day it is.

- Sunday: Light
- Monday: Dark
- Tuesday: Fire
- Wednesday: Water
- Thursday: Plant
- Friday: Electric
- Saturday: Earth

[image: day chart]